# Not sure if I missed some obvious CPU brakes

Tags: c++, optimization, performance

I have three functions (out of a medium 2 digit number of functions) which use up 80% of CPU time, so I kind of wonder if there are points for optimization that I am missing.

Function 1, Extracting a bilinear interpolated point from a width * height float value image:

```
float ExtractBilinear(float* image, int w, int h, float x, float y)
{
    int x0 = (int)floor(x);
    int y0 = (int)floor(y);
    int x1 = x0 + 1;
    int y1 = y0 + 1;
    float c00, c01, c11, c10;
    c00 = c01 = c11 = c10 = 0.0f;

    if(x0 < -1 || x1 > w || y0 < -1 || y1 > h)
    {
        return 0.0f;
    }

    if(x0<0)
    {
        c00 = 0.0f;
        c01 = 0.0f;
    }
    else
    {
        if(y0<0)
        {
            c00 = 0.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            c00 = image[y0*w + x0];
        }
        if(y1 < h)
        {
            c01 = image[y1*w + x0];
        }
        else
        {
            c01 = 0.0f;
        }
    }

    if(x1 < w)
    {
        if(y0<0)
        {
            c10 = 0.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            c10 = image[y0*w + x1];
        }
        if(y1 < h)
        {
            c11 = image[y1*w + x1];
        }
        else
        { 
            c11 = 0.0f;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        c10 = 0.0f;
        c11 = 0.0f;
    }

    float c0 = c10 * (x - x0) + c00 * (x1 - x);
    float c1 = c11 * (x - x0) + c01 * (x1 - x);
    return c1 * (y - y0) + c0 * (y1 - y);
}
```

Function 2: Taking 2 float samples of data (one is image data, one is simulated data), and calculating the sum of squared differences error, with a scalar 'a' to minimize the error as much as possible. SampleX is the size of the input, compX the size of the output, and offX is deprecated, and always 0 (due to legacy code I am keeping it in there).

```
float PatternMatcher::GetSADFloatRel(float* sample, float* compared, int sampleX, int compX, int offX)
{
    if (sampleX != compX)
    {
        return 50000.0f;
    }
    float result = 0;

    float* pTemp1 = sample;
    float* pTemp2 = compared + offX;

    float w1 = 0.0f;
    float w2 = 0.0f;
    float w3 = 0.0f;

    for(int j = 0; j < sampleX; j ++)
    {
        w1 += pTemp1[j] * pTemp1[j];
        w2 += pTemp1[j] * pTemp2[j];
        w3 += pTemp2[j] * pTemp2[j];
    }               
    float a = w2 / w3;
    result = w3 * a * a - 2 * w2 * a + w1;
    return result / sampleX;
}
```

Function 3: a 2 dimensional convolution over the image with rotations being applied. This is working multi-threaded, and is, actually, the most CPU intensive function in our whole algorithm.

`Input`: image is the original float image.

`convolution_image` holds the highest result for that particular thread (I start #CPU Cores - 2 threads, and each thread has its own copy of `convolution_image`, `r_map_image` and `orientation_map_image`).

`r_map_image` saves the currently found radius at that position (with highest convolution value). `orientation_map_image` saves the angle, and goes from 0..180.

`middleReflex` is a pre-calculated map of where the image has to be invalidated due to unavoidable reflexes happening in the optical system.

`kernel1DAll` holds the pre-calculated sample of what an area has to look like to be used later in the algorithm.

`startMin`, `startMax` hold the angles in which the calculation for the current thread should run (for example, with 3 threads, 0..60, 61..120, 121..180)

`outer` is a Circle, containing a position (2D coordinates), and a radius, and every point outside that circle is completely unimportant and should be ignored.

```
void rotateImageConvolution(float* image, float* convolution_image, unsigned char* r_map_image, unsigned char* orientation_map_image, unsigned char* middleReflex, float* kernel1DAll, int startMin, int startMax, Circle outer)
{
    const int imgsize = Width*Height;
    printf("Started thread from %d to %d\n", startMin, startMax);

    float half_w = Width/2.0f;
    float half_h = Height/2.0f;
    const int radius =  int(sqrt(half_w*half_w + half_h*half_h) + 0.5f);
    const int RotateW = 2*radius + 1;
    const int s = RotateW * RotateW; //* nAngles;

    float* rotate_image = (float*)malloc(s*sizeof(float));
    float* summingup_image = (float*)malloc(s*sizeof(float));

    for(int a = startMin ; a<startMax ; a++)
    {
        float theta = (float)(PI*a/nAngles);
        const float costheta = cos(theta);
        const float sintheta = sin(theta);
        Cos[a] = costheta;
        Sin[a] = sintheta;

        for(int j = 0; j<RotateW; j++)
        {
            int y = j - radius;
            float ysina = y*sintheta;
            float ycosa = y*costheta;
            for(int i = 0; i<RotateW; i++)
            {
                int x = i - radius;

                float xf = x*costheta - ysina + Width/2;
                float yf = x*sintheta + ycosa + Height/2;

                rotate_image[j*RotateW + i] = ExtractBilinear(image, Width, Height, xf, yf);
            }
        }

        for(int j = 0; j<RotateW; j++)
        {
            int yoff = j*RotateW;
            float subSum = 0.0f;
            int num = 0;
            for(int kx=0; kx<=half_Integ_L && kx < RotateW; kx++)
            {               
                subSum += rotate_image[yoff + kx];
                num++;
            }

            summingup_image[yoff] = subSum/num;

            for(int i=1; i<RotateW; i++)
            {
                float sum = subSum;
                int istart = i - half_Integ_L;
                int iend = i + half_Integ_L;

                if(istart>=0)
                {
                    num--;
                    subSum -= rotate_image[yoff + istart];
                }
                if(iend<RotateW)
                {
                    num++;
                    float endv = rotate_image[yoff + iend];
                    sum += endv;
                    subSum += endv;
                }

                summingup_image[yoff+i] = sum/num;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<imgsize;i++)
        {
            if(middleReflex[i] == 0xFF)
            {
                convolution_image[i] = 0.0f;
                r_map_image[i] = 10;
                orientation_map_image[i] = 0;
                continue;
            }

            int x = i%Width - Width/2;
            int y = i/Width - Height/2;

            float d = sqrt((i/Width - outer.y) * (i/Width - outer.y) + (i%Width - outer.x) * (i%Width - outer.x));
            if(d >= outer.r-16)
            {
                convolution_image[i] = 0.0f;
                r_map_image[i] = 10;
                orientation_map_image[i] = 0;
                continue;
            }

            int xx = (int)floor(x*costheta + y*sintheta + radius + 0.5f);
            int yy = (int)floor(-x*sintheta + y*costheta + radius + 0.5f);

            float I[KWIDTH];
            for(int ky=-half_MaxK; ky<=half_MaxK; ky++)
            {
                int dy = yy + ky;
                int ii = ky+half_MaxK;

                if(dy >= 0 && xx >=0 && dy < RotateW && xx < RotateW)
                {
                    I[ii] = summingup_image[dy*RotateW + xx];
                }
                else I[ii] = 0.0f;
            }

            for(int ik = NKernel-1; ik>=0; ik--)
            {
                float *pKernel = kernel1DAll + ik*KWIDTH;

                float convrst = 0.0f;

                int r0 = ik + half_MinK;
                for(int x0 = -r0; x0<=r0; x0++ )
                {
                    int ii = x0 + half_MaxK;
                    convrst += (I[ii]*pKernel[KWIDTH-ii-1]);                
                }

                if(convolution_image[i] <= convrst)
                {
                    convolution_image[i] = convrst;
                    r_map_image[i] = (unsigned char)r0;
                    orientation_map_image[i] = (unsigned char)a;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    free(summingup_image);
    free(rotate_image);
}
```

Am I doing something horribly wrong with this code with regards to performance? The code does what it is supposed to do, but unless running on a high-end system, it can take really long to finish.

Comment: From a language use standpoint, things like `if (cond) var = thing; else var = other_thing;` can be shortened using the ternary operator, making your code shorter and scan better in my eyes.

Comment: Is `float` faster than `double` on your platform?  On my Intel Mac `double` can be much quicker.  Your arrays etc may need to be in `float` for space reasons, but perhaps the functions can use `double` internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pre-computing things is useful when it is possible. As some one has already said in your case may be advisable to precomunte things as Width/2. But, if Width is defined through a "Define" your compiler shall be able to do this optimization by itself.

But, I believe that the problem in your code is mainly another one. You have a first loop between startMin and StartMax and than another nested loop from o to imageSize (which i expect being a large number). And this ends up to be the most time expensive part of your code.

There you have other two loops such as:
`for(int ik = NKernel-1; ik>=0; ik--)`
or
`for(int ky=-half_MaxK; ky<=half_MaxK; ky++)`

This you may think that is an "optimized" loop, but actually it isn't, because **the compiler is (generally) designed to be really good at optimizing loops from 0 to N**.

Thus you can have significant improvement. Write your two inner loops in such way and then just compute your index (ik and ky) by subtracting an offset.

Answer (score 2):

How often is the third function called?

The allocation of the images could be a bottleneck. You could try to reuse the memory for the images by passing them to the function instead of reallocating and freeing them every time.

Also things like `Width/2.0f`, `Height/2.0f` and `PI*a/nAngles` should not be evaluated every time they are needed if they are not changed.